# How do you link several objects to another type of an object?

Tags: java, hashmap

I currently am working on an assignment in which we get a text file with a list of countries, the countries' continent, etc...  As a part of the assignment we are supposed to be able to pull up all countries associated to a continent as the user pleases.  I know I can create an ArrayList or something of the sort for each continent, however I am wondering if something like a hashmap would be a viable way to do the same?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Foremost, why do you want to go for HashMap? No doubt, it will make retrieval logic bit easy if you probably can remember the key values you are inserting in the map for each continent.

However, the logic which you can probably go for can be like, you need to parse the list given as an input, and put in each country placed below the name of the continent in a list and put in the HashMap. Now, during retrieval you just need to provide the key and retrieve the list of country for a particular continent.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class TestMaps {
    public void check(HashMap<Integer,List<String>> m) {
        System.out.println(m.get(1));
        //System.out.println(m.get(2));
        System.out.println(m);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap <Integer,List<String>> m = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();
        List <String> ls =new ArrayList<String>();
        ls.add("India");
        ls.add("Indonesia");
        m.put(1, ls);

        TestMaps test=new TestMaps();
        test.check(m);
    }

}
```

Probably, you can also go for String value continent name as a key but an Integer is always a better choice for a key value. However, for a key value to be a String just replace the above code like:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
ls.add("India");
ls.add("Indonesia");
m.put("Asia", ls);
```

Apart from this, you can also use List of List and develop the functionality you need.

Note: You need to have a parsing logic for the input text file. I haven't given the code for the same. I am expecting the input file to be of the type:

```
Continent 1
Country 1
Country 2
Country 3
Country n

Continent 2
Country n

Continent n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can create a <Map> with "Continent" as Key and Collection<Countires> as Value.

    Apply the Collections.sort() - Collection<Countires> when you add it to <Map>.


   e.g. Map map = new HashMap<String, List<String>);
        map.put("Asia", // India, SriLanka.......................);
```